# Please help me ["Windows cannot find "C:\Users\ ..."]

Tags: .net, cmd

I developed a application in VB.NET ...

```
 Dim DIAGTOOL_loc As String = Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\folder\file.exe"
 Dim shellexec As New System.Text.StringBuilder
 shellexec.AppendLine("@echo off")
 shellexec.AppendLine("cls()")
 shellexec.AppendLine(": begin()")
 shellexec.AppendLine("cls()")  
 shellexec.AppendLine("START " & DIAGTOOL_loc.ToString)
 shellexec.AppendLine("pause")
 IO.File.WriteAllText("tester.bat", shellexec.ToString())

 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("tester.bat")
```

Now, when Comand Prompt will open, it should execute file.exe (DIAGTOOL_loc), but when CMD loads, it says "Windows cannot find "C:\Users\ ..."

but why? What's Wrong? The path registered in DIAGTOOL_loc variable works when I type Process.start(DIAGTOOL_loc), so, the file exists ... why cmd don't find it?

this command:

```
shellexec.AppendLine("START " & DIAGTOOL_loc.ToString)
```

should open file.exe ... but it don't work ...

Comment: So, what's the *full* exception message?

Comment: post the content of tester.bat

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
shellexec.AppendLine(String.Format("START """{0}""" , DIAGTOOL_loc))
```

also fix your batch commands:

```
 shellexec.AppendLine("cls")   
 shellexec.AppendLine(":begin")   
 shellexec.AppendLine("cls")
```

Comment: please do you want to rewrite your code? it generate errors ... i'm an intermediate user in .NET

Comment: The error is: The system cannot find the file C:\Users\Administrators\Documents\Visual.                                   HERE IS THE FULL MESSAGE ...   BUT WHY ONLY  C:\Users\Administrators\Documents\Visual.   IS DISPLAYED? iT'S NOT THE FULL PATH ...

Comment: post the content of tester.bat as well.

Comment: START C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\PPT v1.01\PPT\bin\Debug\dgtll\ppi32.exe
pause

Comment: I don't see the " (double quote) around the file. My edit did solve that. Your tester.bat should look like start "c:\Users\ ... dgtll\ppi32.exe"  (notice the double quotes at the start and the end)

Answer (score 0):

In your generated `tester.bat` you will have a line that looks like this:

```
START c:\users\some folders\folder\file.exe
```

As you can see, the path is not quoted, so this will fail if the path contains spaces (which I suspect yours does.

Note that your code could be better written as well - Use [System.IO.Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) to combine parts of a path:

```
 Dim DIAGTOOL_loc As String = _
     """ + Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "\folder\file.exe") + """
```

Comment: i know, but i have also tested this START "My Login Script" C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\killproc.bat in a *.bat file ... (manually) ... and killproc.bat was opened ... and there are no quotes ...

Comment: or simply START C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\killproc.bat

Comment: Please do you want to rewrite your code? it generate errors ... i'm an intermediate user in .NET

Comment: The error is: The system cannot find the file C:\Users\Administrators\Documents\Visual.                                   HERE IS THE FULL MESSAGE ...   BUT WHY ONLY  C:\Users\Administrators\Documents\Visual.   IS DISPLAYED? iT'S NOT THE FULL PATH ...

Comment: As I explained in my answer, that is because you have not put your path in quotes, e.g. `"C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio". The path has spaces so **must** be enclosed in quotes.